# "An error has occurred"

Tags: bug

I have encountered this bug twice today. How? I was reading a question, then I decide I would upvote it and click on the big Puzzling headline to go back to the main page. If the time between the two actions is too small, I see this message for a second: "An error has occurred". One of the times my upvote was not accounted so I had to redo it, but the second time the upvote was correctly counted.

Comment: Sometimes you have to wait a few seconds for your vote to take effect. Especially if your internet connection is slow.

Comment: Well, it is still a bug to me. So I figured I would report it as I couldn't find any topic related to it.

Comment: I suspect it has to do with the performance of the StackExchange servers, but I can't confirm that.  I had a similar problem trying to post a chat message yesterday, and had to retry several times before I could post it.